# Git Multiple Pull Request Error - "An active pull request already exists between these branches"

Tags: git, pull-request

My team is using Git and want to use a single code branch to align with SAFe / XP practices. We are using the Git Pull Request to facilitate "Code Review" but only 1 is allowed at a time. If an existing pull request exists, I get the following error  when trying to create a 2nd one: An active pull request already exists between these branches

This means that subsequent check-ins can be made to the branch resulting in very large PullRequests. It is not feasible for a developer to review code check-ins from multiple developers for multiple stories.

In my previous organization, this was not a problem because you could check-in code against a ticket and easily identify every file modified within the changeset. This made code-review straight forward.

Comment: It would be useful to describe your new process, namely the branching scheme / workflow, for anyone to comment on it.

Comment: Yep, that's how pull requests work. They're between branches and every commit in the source branch is included. It doesn't make sense to have multiple PRs between the same pair of branches.

Answer (score 1):

You said -

> In my previous organization, this was not a problem because you could
>   check-in code against a ticket and easily identify every file modified
>   within the changeset. This made code-review straight forward.

You can still do this with Pull Requests. If you go the commits in a PR, and select any of them, it'll show you the diff between the selected commit and its predecessor. That way, even if a PR has 15 commits, you can still navigate your way through changes in each commit.

Alternate way is to enhance your git flow. You can keep a local branch for each developer working on a story and a feature branch for the story. Raise PRs from local branch to feature branch once individual devs complete their work. And when development of the feature is complete, raise a PR from feature branch to master.

This process will ensure that your earlier PRs to feature branch will be short and sweet and will take less time to review. And in the final PR from feature to master, all the code will be reviewed already and will be ready to be merged.

Comment: The problem is that the PR keeps getting built up with subsequent check-ins making it harder to separate the check-ins from the original Jira ticket. If a PR had a definitive list of changes, I could assign it to the appropriate DEV. But, with multiple devs working, the PR list keeps growing and growing.

Single branch is preferred to eliminate waste and to avoid stale changes sitting in an intermediate branch. By the time the code is merged, it is outdated. Is there another way to perform a code review that doesn't require a PR? Alternative tool? Or, a way to create MULTIPLE PRs?